# Macbook Pro Volume control keys don't control volume, but change the screen to dashboard

Tags: audio, keyboard

Volume control keys don't control volume, but change the screen to dashboard.  If I press the Volume up" key, the screen slides left to the "Dashboard feature.  If I press it again it returns to whatever screen I was on.  It never changes the volume!

Answer (score 0):

Go to: System Preferences

Choose Keyboard

Select Keyboard tab

Uncheck Use all F1, F2, etc. as standard function keys.

Viola!  Problem solved

By default this option is UN checked.